# How to navigate views within an IF statement in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to be able to show a different view depending on IF statements but I am unable to figure it out:

Example:

```
if content == value1 {
     // go to view1
}
if content == value2 {
     // go to view2
}
```

Comment: if/else rather than separate if and == instead of = to start with

Comment: As @Joakim Danielson stated, make sure you're using the Comparison operator, which is `==`. You use `=` to set a variable's value.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that in my example. For my actual code, my only problem is the navigation.

Comment: You have in no way described what your real problem is so you should add a more detailed explanation to your question and some more useful sample code

Comment: Question is unclear. in title you mention navigate within if and in contain show view according if statement. can you please clear me.

Comment: So, I have recieved a response from an API. If this response equals a certain value, I want to display the view corresponding to that value. E.G. If that response was to equal value1 I want to display the view showing information about value1

Comment: @qrpyur See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use if/else, like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    @State private var something: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
           if something {
               View1()
           } else {
               View2()
           }
        }
    }
}
```